# C# Linq query group by in many to many table between many tables

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have the following entities in C#. I want to get the users group by teamname. I tried the following query but the WorkUser is not included in the join. the include statement is not working in the following query.

```
        var query = from gu in DbContext.WorkTeamUsers
                    select gu;

        var query1 = query.Include(x => x.WorkUser);

    var result = await (from team in DbContext.WorkTeams
                        join tgu in query1 on team.WorkTeamId equals tgu.WorkTeamId
                        join u in DbContext.WorkUsers on tgu.UserId equals u.UserId
                        group tgu by tgu.WorkTeam.Name into grp
                        select new
                        {
                            Name = grp.Key,
                            Value = grp.ToList()
                        }).ToListAsync();


public class WorkTeam
{
    [Key]
    public int WorkTeamId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<WorkTeamUser> WorkTeamUsers { get; } 
                                                    = new List<WorkTeamUser>();     
}

public class WorkUser
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int WorkUserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public ICollection<WorkTeamUser> WorkTeamUsers { get; } = new List<WorkTeamUser>();
}

public class WorkTeamUser
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int WorkTeamId { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public WorkTeam WorkTeam { get; set; }

    public WorkUser WorkUser { get; set; }
}
```

The sample data is ashown below:

```
    Table WorkTeamUser:
    =====================
Id  UserId  WorkTeamId
--  ------  ----------
1   2       1
2   11      1
6   10      3
7   15      1
8   16      3

Table WorkUser:
================
UserId  UserName
2       John
11      Bob
10      Daniel
15      Simon
16      Fred


Expected result:

public class Result {
    public string TeamName {get;set;}
    public List<WorkUser> Users {get;set;}
}
```

Can anyone help me to write the correct linq query so that i will get the expected result.

Thanks

Comment: I do not think JOINs are needed.  You need to give more information.  First Result has errors.  There is no string TeamName in any of the classes.  Second there is no class User.  Then you do not have a class WorkTeamGroupUser.  You linq would start like this :  List<Result> result = DbContext.WorkTeams.Select(x => new Result() {

Comment: Hi i have updated my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement to Group or Join.  You are still missing Team Name.  Try following :

```
            List<Result> results = DbContext.WorkTeams.Select(x => new Result() {
                TeamName = x.Name,
                 Users = x.WorkTeamUsers.Select(y => y.WorkUser).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks but this generates 3 queries on the database. one to select the teams first and separate queries for each team to get list of usrs.

Comment: Why do you need 3 queries?  Can't the data get extract from the classes?  Looks like you are doing it the hard way.

Comment: no i mean ur code creates 3 queries in the database when i executed ur line of code and checked in sql profiler.

Comment: So what is wrong with 3 queries?  Otherwise you have to use Joins in c#.  It is a trade-off which is better.

Comment: oh ok. i didn't know about that trade-off thing. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
        var result = await (from g in DbContext.WorkTeamUsers
                   group g.WorkUser by g.WorkTeam.Name into grp
                   select new
                   {
                       TeamName = grp.Key,
                       Users = grp.ToList()
                   }).ToListAsync();
```